# how to extract rows of the date of the last row in a dataframe and if date is not present then pick the previous date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the dates and some other columns and I want to pick all the dates as of the last date of the dataframe for all the months present in that dataframe and if the dates are not present then pick the previous date.

```
eg.
    Date         Month    Year
0   2018-03-21   3        2018
1   2018-03-22   3        2018
2   2018-03-25   3        2018
3   2018-03-26   3        2018
4   2018-03-27   3        2018
...
77  2020-05-12   5        2020
78  2020-05-13   5        2020
```

so I want to extract all the 13th between these dates and if 13 is not present let's say Saturday and Sunday is excluded the datapoint is not there for these two days then we need to check whether 13 is on Sunday if it is on Sunday then we have to pick Friday that is 11 and if it is Saturday then 12. Like that I want all the dates in a separate dataframe.

I have got this much by doing this

```
df[df['Date'][i].day==df['Date'].iloc[-1].day]    # i is the looping variable to get the indices
```

but it prints only the rows with the same date as the last one but there can be some months that are left behind so I want to extract date prior to this day.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build filters that have the behavior you want by extracting the day and the weekday (encoded as Monday=0 to Sunday=6) from your date.

```
business_day = (df["Date"].dt.day == 13) & (df["Date"].dt.weekday < 5)
if_saturday_use_friday = (df["Date"].dt.day == 12) & (df["Date"].dt.weekday == 4)
if_sunday_use_friday = (df["Date"].dt.day == 11) & (df["Date"].dt.weekday == 4)
```

Now you have to link the filters with an logical OR using the `|` operator and apply the filter.

```
df[business_day | if_saturday_use_friday | if_sunday_use_friday]
```